# Adjusted R Squared formula - why is it that it's lower when it shold be higher given the calculation?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

As I understand it, the formula for R2 is:

```
1 - (Var Residuals / Var Actuals)
```

The book Open Intro Statistics has this example:

> Guided Practice 8.10  The variance of the residuals for the model
> given in Guided Practice 8.7 is 23.34, and the variance of the total
> price in all the auctions is 83.06. Calculate R2 for this model.

```
1 - (VarResiduals / VarActuals) = 
1 - (23.34 / 83.06) = 0.72
```

So far so good.

However, if the adjusted R2 is `R2 * (n - 1 / n - k - 1)` where n is sample size and k is number of predictors, then the denominator in the brackets will always be lower than the numerator `(n - 1 > n - k -1)`. Therefore, the result will be a number greater than 1 and therefore shouldn't adjusted R2 always be greater than R2?

```
Adjusted R2 = R2 * [a number greater than 1]
```

My understanding was that adjusted R2 is intended to be a tougher evaluator of model fit. But if I'm reading the formula correct, shouldn't it always be a value greater than R2 since the right hand side of the multiplication sign in `R2 * (n - 1 / n - k - 1)` will always be greater than 1, because the numerator will always be greater than the denominator.

I don't follow this calculation, any guidance appreciated.

Here's the formula from page 377 of [Open Intro Statistics](https://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php):
[image]

Comment: Check your adjusted formula?

Comment: Hi @SmallChess, I added a screenshot from the text book I was studying. Looking at the deduced formula on the right of the = sign, I understood the first component to be the R2 formula and then the right side to be the part I'm questioning. won't it always be greater than 1?

Comment: To me, the left part is not R2.

Comment: Check your order of operations.  The RHS is not $R^2$ times a number greater than 1.

Comment: Maybe easier to memorize is the following formula for adjusted R-squared: 1 - (Var* Residuals / Var Actuals), where Var* uses n-number of parameters in the denominator and equals the square of the residual standard error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no mistake, it's quite clear that for $k>0$ and $R^2<1$ that  $R^2_\text{adj}$ is smaller than $R^2$.

Look at the formula closely. You multiply $1-R^2$  by a number greater than $1$ and *then subtract that larger quantity from* $1$, resulting in a smaller quantity than $R^2$.

Or working through it algebraically:

\begin{eqnarray}
R^2_\text{adj} &=& 1-(1-R^2) \times \frac{n-1}{n-k-1}\\
               &=& R^2 \times \frac{n-1}{n-k-1}-\frac{k}{n-k-1}\\
               &=& R^2-\frac{k}{n-k-1}(1-R^2)\\
               &\leq& R^2
\end{eqnarray}

with the inequality being strict when $k>0$ and $R^2<1$.